# Spark -Reading Terradata table and upsert into Oracle table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am reading data from a Terradata table using spark  and want to **Upsert** the table in Oracle. I am able to insert the data but can I perform UPSERT ?

This is how I am inserting the data into Oracle.

dataframe.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url, table6, props)

Comment: guys anyone please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have scheduled the spark job to run once a day and overwriting the table using dataframe.write.mode(SaveMode.**Overwrite**).jdbc(url, table, props). So that every time the spark job runs it will fetch all the data from Teradata table and overwrite the table in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

There is no upsert in Spark as of Spark 2.2.

So, the ways to achieve it can be:

1. Iterate over the data and figure out using foreach, foreachpartition
2. You can very well do it in a parallel fashion by using writeStream over Dataset and overriding the open(), close() and process() methods in ForeachWriter to insert/update your message.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @abhay for the reply but streaming cant be used with it as it is a normal DB and it will be a spark job. It will be very helpful if you can show me a small sample code of  your solution